# iOS Safari play sound without user interaction

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

**Background:**

To trigger a sound in a webpage notification under iOS safari

**Fact:**

I realized that safari doesn't allow sound to play without DOM interaction according to its autoplay audio policy. User has to interact with DOM after first loading of the application in someway to play sounds.

```
setInterval(function(){
       if(condition)
       sound.play();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
```

Works:

Plan B would be the iOS safari push notification but currently it is not released until 2023 later.

I would like to seek for your advice the solution or alternative to implement a sound trigger webpage under a scheduled interval in webpage.

Thanks.

Comment: When would you need to display a "notification" without user interaction?

Comment: The program scans the API via axios to check the notification. If there is content in the JSON payload, the notification will be prompted and play sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can play any sound after the first DOM interaction. So for example, make the user click a button, like the login button, and play one (silent) sound. After that, you are free to make sounds on interval.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in my case, unfortunately

Comment: In my case, unfortunately, playing a silent voice everytime the User plans to start an Audio was the way to have audio working for Webkit browsers in Mobile. Thanks Apple for such a great policies! Lol